# Тип светильника над входом в подъезд

Tags: грамотная-речь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это нас встречает у подъезда, рассеивающее свет? Лампа, навесной фонарный светильник?

Как определить тип светильника? Фонарь - это только то, что висит на столбах или несется в руке?

Answer (score 1):

Светильник такого типа обычно называют "плафон".

Answer (score 1):

В целом, это настенный светильник. И светильник плафонного типа (так как состоит из плафона, прикрепленного на основании прямо к поверхности).

Непосредственно *плафоном* обычно называют сам абажур, стеклянную часть светильника, закрывающую лампу. Плафон можно найти и на подвесной люстре.

Плафон, словарь Ушакова:

> Абажур в форме полушария для ламп на потолке (спец.).

Словарь Ожегова:

> Род абажура для светильника, обычно на потолке или на стене.

*Фонарём* изначально называли переносной или обособленный (отдельно стоящий, висящий) уличный осветительный прибор, в котором источник света окружён стеклом, по аналогии с архитектурными фонарями (круглое или многогранное в плане сооружение с большими оконными проемами, венчающее купол или какое-либо другое перекрытие и служащее для их естественного освещения). И сейчас под *настенным фонарём* подразумевают традиционный обособленный осветительный прибор, укрепленный на стене на кронштейне.

Если бы во времена первых фонарей существовали и получили массовое распространение такие настенные осветительные приборы, как на фото, то их, скорее всего, назвали бы настенными фонарями по аналогии со всеми остальными (был *проекционный фонарь* – то, что стало потом *проектором,* были *каретные фонари, буферные фонари* – фонари, стоявшие на паровозах). Но сейчас название *настенный фонарь* вступит в конфликт с вышеупомянутыми классическими настенными фонарями (источниками света, которые крепятся к стене на ножке или на подвесе).

Comment: Отдельно стоящий фонарь - это фонарь практически любого рода. Это означает, что бра, люстру или настольную лампу раньше называли фонарем? А сейчас такое их обозначение некорректно?

Comment: @Владимир нет, фонари были предназначены для уличного освещения. Люстры появились задолго до фонарей для освещения помещений. У люстр есть свое определение: _подвесной осветительный прибор на несколько источников света для общего освещения помещений_. Таким образом, люстра даже формально не попадает под определение фонаря. Это разные по типу и по назначению осветительные приборы. На Руси люстры были известны как паникадило. То же самое касается бра и остального. Это не фонари.